# Cambiar campo de formulario por opción de selección

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo el siguiente código

```
<div class="container">
          <p class="caption">Pide tus productos aquí.</p>
          <div class="divider"></div>
          <form class="formValidate" id="formValidate" method="post" action="place-order.php" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col s12 m4 l3">
                <h4 class="header">Ordenar productos</h4>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <table id="data-table-customer" class="responsive-table display" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Precio del producto/Precio</th>
                        <th>Seleccionar</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM items  where not deleted;");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo '<tr><td>'.$row["name"].'</td><td>'.$row["price"].'</td>';                      
          echo '<td><div class="input-field col s12"><label for='.$row["id"].' value="">Quantity</label>';     
                    echo '<input id="'.$row["id"].'" name="'.$row['id'].'" type="text" data-error=".errorTxt'.$row["id"].'"><div class="errorTxt'.$row["id"].'"></div></td></tr>';
                }
                ?>`
```

Lo que permite que se visualice en mi sitio web lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo días intentando cambiar el input-field por un input de opción, de modo que ya el campo de introducir Cantidad no exista, sino poder seleccionar la opción y que se envíe por defecto con el valor del id. Alguna ayuda por favor?

ESTO ES LO QUE ESPERO QUE HAGA:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes poner una imagen de ejemplo para saber qué esperas?

Comment: Hola, ya anexé la imagen al final!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que cambiar tu tipo de `input` de `text` a [`checkbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/checkbox)

Entonces, nos centramos en la parte de tu while:

```
<?php 
    //...
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM items  where not deleted;");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row["name"].'</td><td>'.$row["price"].'</td>';                      
    echo '<td><div class="input-field col s12"><label for='.$row["id"].' value="">Quantity</label>';     
    /*1. Comentamos la vieja línea*/
    //echo '<input id="'.$row["id"].'" name="'.$row['id'].'" type="text" data-error=".errorTxt'.$row["id"].'"><div class="errorTxt'.$row["id"].'"></div></td></tr>';
    /*2. Agreguamos esta nueva línea para dibujar el input de tipo checkbox*/
    echo '<input id="'.$row["id"].'" name="'.$row['id'].'" type="checkbox" data-error=".errorTxt'.$row["id"].'"></td></tr>';
    //...
}
?>
```

1. Comentamos esta línea de código que ya no usarás y que dibujaba antes el input de tipo `text`
2. Agregamos la línea con el input de tipo `checkbox` que nos permitirá verlo así como esperas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Plus

Si necestias obtener el valro del id que ocupas en cada vuelta de tu ciclo, lo puedes obtener con javascript con un evento [`onchange`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

Te voy a dejar el ejemplo suponiendo que ya tenemos el HTML construido de la tabla con todo y el input para que obtengas la respuesta al momento que lo marquen o desmarquen, respectivamente:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mi_tabla = $('#factura').DataTable({
        "language": {
          "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json"
        },
        "bDestroy": true                               
    });  
});
    
    
function validar(id, elemento) {
  //si estan checando el checkbox
  if (elemento.checked) {
    alert("el valor de id es --> " + id + " y han activado el checkbox ");
  }
  //si estaba checado y lo regresan a no checado
  else {
    alert("el valor de id es --> " + id + " y han desactivado el checkbox ");
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="factura">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Precio del producto/Precio</th>
      <th>Seleccionar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 4</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="validar(4, this)">
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>Item 5</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="validar(5, this)">
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>Item 6</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="validar(6, this)">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Es importante saber que esto que vas a modificar:

```
<?php 
    //...
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM items  where not deleted;");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row["name"].'</td><td>'.$row["price"].'</td>';                      
    echo '<td><div class="input-field col s12"><label for='.$row["id"].' value="">Quantity</label>';     
    /*1. Comentamos la vieja línea*/
    //echo '<input id="'.$row["id"].'" name="'.$row['id'].'" type="text" data-error=".errorTxt'.$row["id"].'"><div class="errorTxt'.$row["id"].'"></div></td></tr>';
    /*2. Agreguamos esta nueva línea para dibujar el input de tipo checkbox*/
    echo '<input id="'.$row["id"].'" name="'.$row['id'].'" type="checkbox" data-error=".errorTxt'.$row["id"].'"></td></tr>';
    //...
}
?>
```

Va a verse generado como el ejemplo que te simulé. Espero te sea de ayuda.

Notas adicionales:

1. Ocupé la versión de JQuery 1.12.4
2. Ocupé la versión 1.10 de [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda. Me funcionó correctamente. Te pasaste!!

Answer (score 0):

yo por lo generar cuando trabajo con select que tiene option desde la BD lo hago así:

```
<select name="filtro" id="filtro">
<option value="1" selected>Seleccionar integrante</option>
<?php
    $sqlEquipo="SELECT equipoid, nombre FROM equipo where proyecto_id=1";
    $resultEquipo=$base->prepare($sqlEquipo);
    $resultEquipo->execute();
    while ($rowEquipo=$resultEquipo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

       echo '<option value="'.$rowEquipo['equipoid'].'">'.$rowEquipo['nombre'].'</option>';

     }
   ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Considera leer [answer]